# map many models with function referencing data from nested columns, non nested columns and nested lists in purrr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to do analysis on nested models by applying functions that can be categorized as the following:

1. referencing data from nested column with arguments fixed in the function
2. referencing data from nested column with arguments referenced dynamically as listed column
3. referencing data from nested column with arguments referenced dynamically in a non-listed column
4. referencing data from nested column with arguments directly referenced

help:

1. I can't get `make_data_input` formula to work regardless if its nested data or non nested data
2. I can't get the `make_data_input` formula to in a nested data set at all

```
library(tidyverse)

#This work 

make_data_fixed <- function(df) {

  df %>% 
    mutate(price_cumsum=cumsum(price),
           max_price_cumsum=max(price_cumsum))
}


# the max column is not calculating the max column of price but instead pulling the prie_cumsum column values it pulls in the literal value
make_data_input <- function(df,x) {
  df %>% 
    mutate("{{x}}_cumsum":=cumsum({{x}}),
           "max_{{x}}_cumsum":=max("{{x}}_cumsum")
           )
}


selected_cols <- c("clarity","depth")


calculate_stuff <- function(df,x) {
  df %>% 
    summarize(across({x},
                    ~length(
                      unique(.)
                      )
                    )
              )
}

calculate_stuff(diamonds,selected_cols)



diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut,color) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(test=list(selected_cols),
         carat="carat") %>% 
  mutate(simple=map(data,make_data_fixed),# this works
         calculate_direct=map2(.x=data,.y=test,~calculate_stuff(df=.x,x=.y)), # this works
         calculate_indirect=map2(.x=data,.y=carat,~calculate_stuff(df=.x,x=.y)), # this works
         complex=map2(.x=data,.y=price,~make_data_input(df=.x,.y=price)) # this doesn't work
         )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do two things. First, use `dplyr::rowwise()` instead of `purrr::map` this makes it much easier to read and reason about the code. It is also easier to understand which object names go into the functions.

Second, we need to correct `make_data_input`. You use `max("{{x}}_cumsum")` but `"{{x}}_cumsum"` is nothing more than a string. We need to first create a string based on `"{{x}}_cumsum"` and we do this with `rlang::englue()` and can then use this inside `.data[[]]` or alternatively `!! sym()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

make_data_fixed <- function(df) {
  
  df %>% 
    mutate(price_cumsum=cumsum(price),
           max_price_cumsum=max(price_cumsum))
}

make_data_input <- function(df, x) {
  df %>%
    mutate("{{x}}_cumsum" := cumsum({{x}}),
           "max_{{x}}_cumsum" := max(.data[[rlang::englue("{{x}}_cumsum")]])
    )
}

selected_cols <- c("clarity","depth")

calculate_stuff <- function(df,x) {
  df %>% 
    summarize(across({x},
                     ~length(
                       unique(.)
                     )
    )
    )
}

diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut,color) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(test=list(selected_cols),
         carat="carat") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(simple = list(make_data_fixed(data)),
         calculate_direct = list(calculate_stuff(data, test)), 
         calculate_indirect = list(calculate_stuff(data, carat)), 
         complex = list(make_data_input(data, price)) 
  ) %>% 
  pull(complex) %>% 
  .[[1]]

#> # A tibble: 3,903 x 10
#>    carat clarity depth table price     x     y     z price_cumsum
#>    <dbl> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <int>
#>  1  0.23 SI2      61.5    55   326  3.95  3.98  2.43          326
#>  2  0.26 VVS2     62.9    58   554  4.02  4.06  2.54          880
#>  3  0.7  SI1      62.5    57  2757  5.7   5.72  3.57         3637
#>  4  0.59 VVS2     62      55  2761  5.38  5.43  3.35         6398
#>  5  0.74 SI2      62.2    56  2761  5.8   5.84  3.62         9159
#>  6  0.7  VS2      60.7    58  2762  5.73  5.76  3.49        11921
#>  7  0.74 SI1      62.3    54  2762  5.8   5.83  3.62        14683
#>  8  0.7  SI1      60.9    57  2768  5.73  5.76  3.5         17451
#>  9  0.6  VS1      61.7    55  2774  5.41  5.44  3.35        20225
#> 10  0.7  SI1      62.7    55  2774  5.68  5.74  3.58        22999
#> # ... with 3,893 more rows, and 1 more variable: max_price_cumsum <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: hey! thanks! in general how do you approach when to use rowwise() vs. purrr()? Are there any performance issues I need to think about? my dataset has 100+ columns and $2M+ rows

Comment: @alejandro_hagan we would need to run a benchmark. Both `purrr::map` and `rowwise` are using loops. `map` is implementend in C, but the function you apply is an R function so I guess it only depends on how much more (or less) overhead `rowwise()` has compared to `map()`.

Comment: in general, do you have a suggestion when to use map() vs. rowwise()? I was imitating the framework of what I've seen others do with nested models so unsure if that is still an advantaged approach